# IPv6 : Access comcast delegated 2601 /64 internal network over the internet

Tags: networking, routes, ipv6

I'm trying to understand how IPv6 networks work.

I have been assigned a 2001: /128 addreess by Comcast (my ISP) for my internet facing cable modem (c300-100NAS Netgear).

I have received a system deligated prefix of 2601:243:1501:xxxx::/60
and a **LAN deligated prefix for my internal network 2601:243:1501:xxxx::/64**

This automatically assigned ip address of 2601:: /64 network to all devices in my internal network at home. I can even connect to each other using these ip addresses. But when i access these from the internet, i am not able to reach them. I think i am missing the routes for the 2601 /64 networks that lead into my home. (these are acting similar to ipv4 private addresses)

**Q1: what is the difference between system and LAN deligated prefixes**

**Q2: What should i do to be able to access my machines over the internet using 2601::/64 address.** I am typically looking to use ssh and http ports.

Thanks you your help in advance.

Comment: This question is not about programming, within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic]. You may be able to get help on [su].

Comment: Thanks I have [re-posted this question on super-user](http://superuser.com/questions/1113954/ipv6-access-comcast-delegated-2601-64-internal-network-over-the-internet)